# Deserializing LocalDateTime with Feign

Tags: java, date, localdate, spring-cloud-feign

I'm getting an exception when trying to deserialize JSON POST response which includes LocalDateTime field.

```
feign.codec.DecodeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

Below is the response in JSON format:

```
{
  "date":"2018-03-18 01:00:00.000"
}
```

This is how I create my remote service:

```
@PostConstruct
void createService() {
    remoteService = Feign.builder()
            .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
            .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
            .target(RemoteInterface.class, remoteUrl);
}
```

How can I force Feign to deserialize the date to LocalDateFormat?

Comment: how you deserialize it, can you show us your code please?

Comment: @YCF_L , Thank you for your comment. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 5):

I've resolved the issue by creating own `GsonDecoder` with custom type adapters:

```
public class CustomGsonDecoder extends GsonDecoder {

    public CustomGsonDecoder(){
        super(new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
                @Override
                public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                    return LocalDateTime.parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString(), dtf);
                }
            }).registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime>() {
                @Override
                public JsonElement serialize(LocalDateTime localDateTime, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
                    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                    return new JsonPrimitive(dtf.format(localDateTime));
                }
            }).create());
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. And thanks for sharing your solution. You may declare just one static date time formatter in the class rather then instantiating one each time. It’s thread safe, so shouldn’t pose a problem even if multiple responses are processed in parallel.